# Radio input Checked CSS not working

Tags: css, radio-button, shopify, liquid

I was wondering if someone could help me, Im having a bit of trouble with a radio button which Im implementing for my filters in my site. Its a special radio button CSS, here is the code:

```
     /** radio buttons style **/
  input[type=checkbox]:not(old),
  input[type=radio   ]:not(old){
    width     : 2em;
    margin    : 0;
    padding   : 0;
    font-size : 1em;
    opacity   : 0;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label,
  input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label{
    display      : inline-block;
    margin-left  : -2em;
    line-height  : 1.5em;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label > span,
  input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label > span{
    display          : inline-block;
    width            : 0.875em;
    height           : 0.875em;
    margin           : 0.25em 0.5em 0.25em 0.25em;
    border           : 0.0625em solid rgb(192,192,192);
    border-radius    : 0.25em;
    background       : rgb(224,224,224);
    background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
    background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
    background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
    background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
    background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
    vertical-align   : bottom;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label > span,
  input[type=radio   ]:not(old):checked + label > span{
    background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
    background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
    background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
    background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
    background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label > span:before{
    content     : '✓';
    display     : block;
    width       : 1em;
    color       : rgb(153,204,102);
    font-size   : 0.875em;
    line-height : 1em;
    text-align  : center;
    text-shadow : 0 0 0.0714em rgb(115,153,77);
    font-weight : bold;
  }
  input[type=radio]:not(old):checked + label > span > span{
    display          : block;
    width            : 0.5em;
    height           : 0.5em;
    margin           : 0.125em;
    border           : 0.0625em solid rgb(115,153,77);
    border-radius    : 0.125em;
    background       : rgb(153,204,102);
    background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
    background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
    background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
    background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
    background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  }
  /** end radio buttons style **/
```

Here is the HTML/Liquid code on the server side:

```
{% assign current_tags_dc = current_tags | downcase %}
{% assign all_tags_dc = collection.all_tags | downcase %}
<!-- Heading -->
<h2>Marcas</h2>
<!-- Sidebar Menu -->
<ul class="clearfix filters list-unstyled my-list brand-list">
  <!-- {% assign marcas_tags = current_tags | downcase %}  {{ marcas_tags }} -->
  <li>
    <input class="coll-filter" id="marca-all" type="radio" name="marcas" value="" />
    <label for="marca-all"><span><span></span></span>&nbsp;Quitar Selección</label>
  </li>
  {% for product_vendor in collection.all_vendors %}
    {% assign tag = product_vendor | downcase %}
    {% if current_tags_dc contains tag %}
      <li>
        <input class="coll-filter" id="marca-{{ product_vendor | handle }}" type="radio" name="marcas" checked value="{{ product_vendor | handle }}" /> 
        <label for="marca-{{ product_vendor | handle }}" class="checked"><span><span></span></span>&nbsp;{{ product_vendor }}</label>
      </li>
    {% elsif all_tags_dc contains tag %}
      <li>
         <input class="coll-filter" id="marca-{{ product_vendor | handle }}" type="radio" name="marcas" value="{{ product_vendor | handle }}" /> 
         <label for="marca-{{ product_vendor | handle }}">
           <span><span></span></span>&nbsp;{{ product_vendor }}
         </label>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The problem is that the radio input IS checked but the mark does not appear when the page is reloaded to filter out the list. On the image you can see on the code that the checked option is on the radio input, but no mark is on the preview.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? You can watch the preview here:

http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/collections/panales-toallitas/aden-anais?preview_theme_id=143428481

If you test any other option in "Marcas" the mark does show after the reload to filter the products, but in the case of "Aden + Anais", "Babysec" and the options in the other radio groups, the radio is not marked when the collection page is reloaded. Even if the radio button has the checked property. Any ideas why this might be happening? :P

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML to your question to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Well I found out a work around thanks to a person who helped me on Facebook :P What he suggested since Im working with a custom radio button css I could to aim at the radio css with a .checked class instead of the checked property on the radio button. So the solution would look something like this:

```
 label.checked > span > span{
    display          : block;
    width            : 0.5em;
    height           : 0.5em;
    margin           : 0.125em;
    border           : 0.0625em solid rgb(115,153,77);
    border-radius    : 0.125em;
    background       : rgb(153,204,102);
    background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
    background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
    background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
    background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
    background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  }
```

Then all I would have to do is add the `class="checked"` to the label from the checked radio and presto. This is a bit of a dirty solution cause it allows the css to "select" two radio buttons. If you select one option and then select another one after the reload, both boxes will be shown to be selected. But this solution does not affect the functionality of the multiple filters for the Shopify Collection Im using, so for now Ill stay with that solution haha.

If anyone knows why a checked radio button would not be shown to be checked if it has the checked property, I would like to hear the hypothesis haha.

If anyone has any questions about this Ill be happy to help :D

Cheers!